# Fitting text into a fixed-size div

Tags: javascript, css, string, html, fill

I have a fixed size `div` which I need to fill with text. I need to only fill it with as much text will fit into it, and I need to know the offset in the string where it cut off.

Right now I am doing it by saving the `div`'s current height then setting the `div`'s height to `auto`, taking increasingly long substrings of the string and putting them into the `div`, and stopping when the `div`'s height gets bigger than the original height. This works, but it's pretty inefficient.

Is there any better way to do this? And by better I mean faster.

Comment: I am working on it right now. But I have a question. What are the width/height of your div to put the text in?

Comment: @William it shouldn't matter, the function to do this should be able to take any fixed-size div and fill it (my current one does this). I don't need you to write the whole function for me though, I can do that, I just need to know the method of determining how much text to put in. Thanks for working on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I came up with this: http://jsfiddle.net/r5Njr/. That should fit the text into the div. If you want to be fancy, you can change the last 2 or 3 characters to a ...

Comment: This is exactly what I'm already doing, and I'm doing 50 chars at a time, not 1, and it's still too slow. Thanks though.

Comment: Alright... slight modification. Sounds like you have a lot of text. So, this version cuts it down (by calculation, not removing characters) until it is one line above the desired line. Then it cuts if off by characters. [http://jsfiddle.net/r5Njr/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/r5Njr/2/)

Comment: that seems better, but it always comes up with the same text no matter how wide the div is. For example, look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/r5Njr/5/

Comment: That was because it made the calculations regardless of whether the text fit or not. Now it tests before making the calculations. [http://jsfiddle.net/r5Njr/6/](http://jsfiddle.net/r5Njr/6/)

Comment: I can't test it now, but from what I can see, it looks like this will work nicely. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't get the question correctly but why not use substr and fetch an exact characters number?

Comment: How do I know what the exact characters number is? I only have a div (which is a fixed size) and a string. I need to know how much text from that string to put into the div so that it will exactly fit it.

Comment: well it would always be an aproximation 'cause different chars require a bit more chars. But i would do a trial an error 'til i find an aproximate number of chars. Then just use substr to get that fixed number all the time. If needed check the browser and fetch a different number of chars for different browsers. It's always a aproximation but is fast and should be enough i think

Comment: An approximation isn't good enough, I need it to be exact. Also due to variable-width characters, one text won't even be close to another text.

Comment: That's helpful but doesn't solve my problem. I can't modify the text I'm working with.